# Initialize field to constant value in django Form

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

How can I set up a model/form combination so that the field in the model is initialized to a fixed value and there is no form element displayed when the form is presented to the user?

I just want to initialize `Source.updated = datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)` each time a new `Source` is created from a form.  The user cannot over-ride this initial default. (Subsequent interaction with the app will cause this field value to change, but it's not just `auto_now` because I want the initial value to be far in the past.)

What I have now is

```
class Source(Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=168, help_text="Source name")
    link = models.URLField(primary_key=True, help_text="Data source link")
    type = models.CharField(max_length=64, help_text="Data source type")
    
     # TODO: add this field to the model.
     # have it initialize to 2000-01-01
    #updated = models.DateTimeField(help_text="Most recent time this source has been updated")
```

```
class SourcesForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = models.Source
        fields = ['name', 'link', 'type',]
    # TBD: how to configure the form so that
    # it initializes the "updated" field with a fixed value
    # when .save() is called
```

The logic I'm trying to implement is that: we're getting data from a remote source, so I want to know when the most-recent time this data have been updated is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set [**`editable=False`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#editable) to prevent the field to show up in `ModelForm`s, `ModelAdmin`, etc.:

```
from datetime import datetime

class Source(Model):
    # …
    updated = models.DateTimeField(editable=False, default=datetime(2000, 1, 1), help_text="Most recent time this source has been updated")
```

Comment: Still modifiable in code?  i.e. I can still do `source.updated=datetime.datetime.now(); source.save()`?

Comment: @Dave: yes, or `Source.objects.filter(pk=1425).update(updated=datetime(2021, 12, 10))`, etc. It is a field that you can edit, but by default not by modelforms, modeladmins, etc.